# error while using FontAwesome with xhtml using jdeveloper

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, xhtml, font-awesome

I am trying to use `font-awesome` at my `.xhtml` page, but i get errors as in image below.

I am using Jdeveloper 12.2.1

I read a lot of topics here but couldn't find solution
any help please ?

[image]
**Edit :**

project works well when i use `.html` instead of `.xhtml` file,

so the problem is not happening because of wrong paths.

i think there is still some config missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it worked when i added `../` at the beginning of `href` or by adding

`#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}`

```
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>login</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.ico"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/font-awesome.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../vendor/animate/animate.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../vendor/css-hamburgers/hamburgers.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../vendor/select2/select2.min.css"/>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/util.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css"/>
</h:head>
```